# Will there be any further movies in Baahubali series or any spin-off?

Tags: sequels, baahubali-the-beginning, baahubali-2-the-conclusion

Will there be any further movies in Baahubali series or any spin-off?

Is there any **official** comment on this?

**No opinions please.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Previously [there were plans](http://indiatoday.intoday.in/story/baahubali-3-ss-rajamouli-virtual-reality-vr-experience/1/950173.html) about Baahubali 3

[image]

But now they are all shelved. From [Indiatoday](http://indiatoday.intoday.in/story/baahubali-3-ss-rajamouli-vijayendra-prasad-prabhas-rana/1/947989.html):

> "We are done with the story of Baahubali, there cannot be a third part. But the world and the legacy of Baahubali will live on through a comic series and a TV series," Prabhas told PTI.

As Prabhas said the franchise will still continue with comic and a web series.

And from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baahubali_(franchise)#Tie-ins):

> A prequel novel to the films, titled [The Rise of Sivagami](http://www.baahubali.com/novel/), was released on 31 March 2017. A Graphic novel named [Baahubali: Battle of the Bold](http://www.baahubali.com/graphic-novel/) released in the same month, by Graphic India. An animated series named [Baahubali: The Lost Legends](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5523460/) released in the following month, by Graphic India and Arka Mediaworks